# BM25 similarity with binary term frequencies in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

Does anybody tried to customize BM25 similarity used in Elasticsearch in a following way?
This is a common BM25 score. I want term frequencies to be binary (0 if a term is not presented in the document and 1 if term frequency in the document if greater 0). So in the pic below I want tf(q_i, d) to be {0, 1}.
Any ideas what is the easiest way to achieve this in Elasticsearch?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use the [Unique Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html) which will index only unique tokens during analysis.
This should be equivalent to having a term frequency of 1 in the document if a token exists.